# Google App Engine Python, virtualenv and mimetypes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I have working project built with djangoappengine and running under App Engine dev server. So I run "manage.py runserver" and all works as appreciated. All requirements (django, djangoappengine etc) are located in project root dir. Now I am trying to use virtualenv (I am running commands in project root):

```
virutalenv --no-site-packages env
env\Scripts\python manage.py runserver
```

Server starts, but when I try to access any page I get such exception:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named mimetypes
```

How can I fix this?

PS I am trying to use this idea on Windows: https://bitbucket.org/imbolc/gae-virtualenv/src

Edit 1. The same behaviour is under Ubuntu 10.10.

Edit 2.  The same behaviour is under Mac OS X: [How to use virtualenv with Google App Engine SDK on Mac OS X 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858772/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-google-app-engine-sdk-on-mac-os-x-10-6) . Question can be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use virtualenv with Google App Engine SDK on Mac OS X 10.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858772/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-google-app-engine-sdk-on-mac-os-x-10-6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in [Issue 4339](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4339) for GAE.  Here's how to fix it:

1. Download patch from this Issue comment: [patch](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4339#c2)
2. Move the patch to **google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/**
3. Change your working directory to the same path as above
4. Type: **patch -p0 < dev_appserver.patch**

Comment: That direct link to the patch has a token which seems to expire. The patch is attached to this comment on the issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4339#c2

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv does not copy full Python standard library, but instead bootstraps the loading of these modules with setting sys.path (PYTHONPATH). Looks like Google App Engine does not like this.

I suggest you file a bug against Google App Engine.